# Pandas - Reading excel file from O365

Tags: pandas

I have an excel file in O365 which has been shared and want to be import into pandas but failed. The file is shared as anyone with the link can edit. I’ve went through many related posts but always get different error messages. You can find a link which is a shared excel file. Please help me how to import! Thanks in advance!
[text](https://botizrt-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/bauko_botizrt_onmicrosoft_com/ETu8P8uY5EJChvYhi4tMaqABnOLyU97Ijw2v-pEmM-jXaA)

---

```py
import urllib.request

url = 'https://botizrt-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/bauko_botizrt_onmicrosoft_com/ETu8P8uY5EJChvYhi4tMaqABnOLyU97Ijw2v-pEmM-jXaA'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "test.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append `&download=1` to your url:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://botizrt-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/bauko_botizrt_onmicrosoft_com/ETu8P8uY5EJChvYhi4tMaqABnOLyU97Ijw2v-pEmM-jXaA?rtime=GhHyWm4O20g&download=1'
response = requests.get(url)
with BytesIO() as buf:
    buf.write(response.content)
    df = pd.read_excel(buf)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          date  tavg  tmin  tmax  prcp  snow  wdir  wspd  wpgt    pres  tsun
0   2023-01-01   9.1   5.6  13.5   0.0   NaN   152  12.6  25.9  1029.6   NaN
1   2023-01-02   7.2   1.9  12.9   0.0   NaN   148  10.2  27.8  1027.4   NaN
2   2023-01-03   5.2   1.8   6.7   0.3   NaN   207   5.1  20.4  1027.7   NaN
3   2023-01-04   5.5   3.4   6.9   0.4   NaN   213   7.5  25.9  1029.5   NaN
4   2023-01-05   5.9   3.4   8.6   0.7   NaN   200  17.6  35.2  1019.1   NaN
5   2023-01-06   6.2   2.7   9.0   0.0   NaN   241  13.7  35.2  1022.7   NaN
6   2023-01-07   5.6   1.2  11.1   0.0   NaN   145   7.8  27.8  1023.0   NaN
7   2023-01-08   4.8  -0.5   8.5   0.0   NaN   156  12.0  27.8  1018.6   NaN
8   2023-01-09   7.9   6.5   9.4   3.4   NaN   146  14.7  33.3  1009.3   NaN
9   2023-01-10   6.7   5.2   7.8   5.8   NaN    76  13.7  42.6  1008.0   NaN
10  2023-01-11   5.6   2.8   8.5   2.1   NaN   347  14.4  40.8  1017.8   NaN
11  2023-01-12   5.0   1.5   8.9   0.0   NaN   203   7.7  22.2  1022.4   NaN
12  2023-01-13   4.1   1.6   5.7   0.0   NaN   148   9.8  27.8  1021.7   NaN
13  2023-01-14   3.3   1.0   5.4   2.9   NaN   211   5.6  18.5  1022.8   NaN
14  2023-01-15   5.0   3.6   8.5   0.0   NaN   158  12.0  31.5  1018.0   NaN
15  2023-01-16   5.7   3.7   7.6   2.4   NaN   156  15.0  33.3  1004.5   NaN
16  2023-01-17   8.1   5.5  10.6  11.1   NaN   152  18.9  44.5   995.2   NaN
17  2023-01-18   9.7   6.8  12.0   3.4   NaN   159  19.5  44.5   995.5   NaN
18  2023-01-19   7.8   3.2  11.8  10.5   NaN   182  15.8  40.8  1002.4   NaN
19  2023-01-20   2.5   0.2   4.0  14.1   NaN   312  15.2  35.2  1007.3   NaN
20  2023-01-21   2.4   0.9   3.9   0.7   NaN    35  11.8  25.9  1013.5   NaN
21  2023-01-22   5.4   1.0  11.0   0.3   NaN    10   9.6  22.2  1020.7   NaN
22  2023-01-23   6.5   2.2  12.0   0.0   NaN    10  10.4  24.1  1025.9   NaN
23  2023-01-24   3.7   2.7   5.4   0.0   NaN   254   6.9  20.4  1031.5   NaN
24  2023-01-25   2.6   1.8   3.5   0.0   NaN   287   6.2  22.2  1030.8   NaN
25  2023-01-26   2.0   0.9   3.5   2.1   NaN    41   7.1  24.1  1021.5   NaN
26  2023-01-27   1.0  -0.4   2.6   0.5   NaN   348  14.7  24.1  1014.6   NaN
27  2023-01-28   1.9   0.9   3.2   1.7   NaN   342  15.1  25.9  1018.0   NaN
28  2023-01-29   0.7  -0.9   1.7   0.0   NaN   328  13.1  25.9  1024.5   NaN
29  2023-01-30  -0.2  -4.2   2.5   0.4   NaN   207  14.6  33.3  1018.7   NaN
30  2023-01-31   2.0  -2.4   6.3   0.3   NaN   260  11.8  33.3  1016.1   NaN
```

Comment: Note, `requests` is more or less required here, since Sharepoint uses cookies for the request to be resolved correctly, which does not work out of the box with `urllib`.